# How to set macro variable in the page template for Nunjucks

Tags: templates, gulp, frontend, nunjucks, gulp-nunjucks-render

I am using Nunjucks to set up a complicated site. My folder structure is as such:

```
frontend/
   |- dev/
   |- gulpfile.js
     |- css/
     |- images/
     |- js/
     |- pages/
       |- dashboard.njk
     |- templates/
       |- macros/
         |- header-macro.njk
       |- partials/
         |- _header.njk
         |- three-col.njk
```

I am attempting to have a macro (**header-macro.njk**) that causes the active class to be set on the nav link for the current page. It looks like this:

```
   {% macro active(activePage='dashboard') %}

    <nav class="header__nav">
        <a class="{% if activePage == 'dashboard' %}active{% endif %}" href="#">Dashboard</a>
        <a class="{% if activePage == 'locations' %}active{% endif %}" href="#">Locations</a>
        <a class="{% if activePage == 'reports' %}active{% endif %}" href="#">Reports</a>
        <a class="{% if activePage == 'services' %}active{% endif %}" href="#">Services &#38; Billing</a>
        <a class="{% if activePage == 'people' %}active{% endif %}" href="#">People</a>
    </nav>
{% endmacro %}
```

This would be imported into my **_header.njk** partial like so..

```
<div class="header__inner">
        <div class="header__logo"><img src="/images/logos/STN-y-15x100.png"></div>
            {% import 'macros/header-macro.njk' as nav %}
```

I want to set the nav.active variable in each page template. So in this case, that would be **dashboard.njk**

```
{% set page_title = "Welcome to eServices - Dashboard" %}
{% set body_class = "dashboard" %}
{{nav.active('dashboard')}}
```

But i get an error:

> Error: Unable to call `nav["active"]`, which is undefined or falsey

However, if i set nav.active('dashboard') in the **_header.njk**, everything works.

Am i missing something with the syntax or the folder structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nav` is defined in `_header.njk` scope. This scope is not available in `dashboard.njk` therefore you have `nav` as `undefined`. However you can use `nav` in `_header.njk`.

```
// app.js
var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
var env = nunjucks.configure();

var res = nunjucks.render('dashboard.njk');
console.log(res); 

// dashboard.njk
DASHBOARD
{% set activePage = 'dashboard' %} // Also you can pass it as a render prop.
{% include "header.njk" %}

// header.njk
HEADER
{% import 'macro.njk' as nav %}
{{ nav.active (activePage) }} // pass activePage to macro-scope

// macro.njk
{% macro nav (activePage) %}
<nav class="header__nav">
    <a class="{{ 'active' if activePage == 'dashboard' }}" href="#">Dashboard</a>
    ...        
</nav>
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: Thank you. I needed to move my folder structure in order to make nav available.